# System Verilog using mask

Tags: verilog, mask, system-verilog

I can't get the meaning of this code.
I know VHDL and need system verilog. I do not know the meaning of `bits [num] = '{4, 4})` or  `(output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);`

please explain me

```
module works
  #(parameter int num = 4,
   parameter int width = 8,
   parameter int bits [num] = '{4, 4})
   (output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *module* is like a VHDL *entity*, so we have a block called `works`:

```
module works
```

A *parameter* is like a VHDL *generic*. Instead of saying `generic`, in SystemVerilog we just say `#`. So, we have a block with three parameters (generics), an `int` (32-bit signed integer like a VHDL *integer*) with a default value of 4:

```
#(parameter int num = 4,
```

an `int` with a default value of 8:

```
parameter int width = 8,
```

and an array of `int`s of size equal to the value of the parameter `num`, which will be numbered 0 to `num-1`:

```
parameter int bits [num] = '{4, 4})
```

`'{4,4}` is an *assignment pattern* and is the (rough) equivalent of a VHDL *aggregate*. So, this code is trying to initialise two of the values of this array to to integer 4. The trouble is **this code is probably illegal**. The array `bits` can be of any size (depending on the value of the parameter `num`) and this array is what is called an *unpacked array*. In SystemVerilog (and in Verilog), both the size and shape of assignments to packed arrays must match (just like in VHDL). This size of either side of this assignment will not match unless the value of `num` is 2. If you want to initialise all the elements of an unpacked array to the same thing, you can use a *key* (rather like VHDL `others`):

```
parameter int bits [num] = '{default:4})
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5w8y

This is a port:

```
(output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);
```

whose size is defined by the two parameters, `width` and `num`. The output is an array of `num` (a so-called *unpacked* dimension) of words of width `width` (a so-called *packed* dimension). `logic` is a type. Variables of type `logic` can take one of four values: 0, 1, X or Z.

Answer (score -2):

`output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]`

`[width-1:0] mask` is a vector of width bits. With a width of 8 this would be an 8-bit vecor: `[7:0] mask`.

The vector is followed by [num] means it is an array of 'num' vectors. The total is a two-dimensional array of width x num bits.
That syntax is verry common and you will see it often.

I had to look for the '{4,4} pattern (I could not find it in my little System Verilog booklet) and as Matthew says it is an assignment of values to an array. So, my initial interpretation  was wrong.

The problem with the existing code is that my Verilog simulator throws an error message when using the default values. num is 4 and '{4,4} has only two elements. This upon start-up I get an error:

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-666] expression has 2 elements; expected 4 [...
```

If I set num to 2 `#(.num(2))` the simulator is happy.